# Calling a payable contract function from truffle console

Tags: truffle, payable, truffle-console

Let's say I have this function is a contract, that should enable users to deposit ETH into the contract, and have the contract manage their deposits

```
function deposit() payable public {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
    totalBalances.add(msg.value);
}
```

Now that I have the contract deployed, how do I call this function from the truffle console? That is, with ETH attached.

Comment: No, because this is not the fallback function, it's a specific named payable function.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is the syntax:

```
YourContractName.at('some address').deposit({from:'some address',value:100})
```

Comment: That is what specified in the answer I've flagged you for duplicate content.